# VSIX bindingRedirect not working for System.Data.Common

Tags: c#, .net, vsix

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2017 extension that references several helper libraries as well as the Oracle data client. I was originally using Fody and Costura to weave dependencies into my assembly but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it (for one, it drastically increases build time). I'm trying to get it to work simply using Assets in the `vsixmanifest` file but I'm now getting a very frustrating assembly load error.

Whenever I try to actually make a call to the database, I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` with the message `'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'` originating from my data layer, `MyExtension.DataAccess`. I have done a full text search on the entire solution and ***nothing*** is referencing this version of `System.Data.Common`. I can't even find that version in the GAC or on NuGet.

I've tried using the `app.config` file in both `MyExtension.DataAccess` and `MyExtension.VSIX` to redirect to the version of `System.Data.Common` I'm bundling as an Asset (4.3.0 from NuGet, which appears to be assembly version 4.1.1.0 as per IL Spy):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I have also tried using `4.3.0.0` in `newVersion` and that did not work either. I'm at my wit's end with this. I've tried everything I can think of; I can't even find an other people having this issue on GitHub or Stack Overflow. I've wiped out all the extension data, I've deleted `bin`/`obj` several times to no avail, I have zero more ideas. What's going wrong?

Comment: Ok, looks like it's automatically adding a reference to the System.Data.Common assembly version 4.2.0.0 because I'm using that namespace in some code. Why does it pick 4.2.0.0? That's not even the version installed with the Framework. It doesn't exist in the "Assemblies" browser. The bindingRedirect won't redirect it to another version. I'm very confused how this whole thing is supposed to work.

Comment: Open your output vsix (like a zip file), and check if 1) there's a System.Data.Common in there and if yes 2) check the version. If it's not there or the version is not ok, you need to add this as a reference to your project, so it can end up in this vsix properly.

Comment: I've already done that; there is a System.Data.Common but it's the wrong version. It's 4.1.1.0 from the 4.3.0 version of the NuGet package. The `DataAccess` assembly is referencing 4.2.0.0, so it throws an exception. It looks like I'm actually getting the 4.2.0.0 version in the output folder of the `DataAccess` assembly, however, so I'm going to try and include that in the VSIX. I'm not sure where that version is coming from because the system-wide search I ran didn't yield any versions that matched 4.2.0.0.

Comment: That seemed to work; it seems it's using the assembly version from wherever the framework is installed and not whatever version I explicitly reference. App.config redirect bindings have no effect. Removing all extraneous references from the project, cleaning, and rebuilding made it copy the correct version to the library's output folder, which i then copied into the VSIX project and included as an asset. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line: implicit assembly references from .NET Framework assemblies forcibly override all other references to the same assembly. `bindingRedirect` entries in `app.config` have no effect. Apparently Visual Studio doesn't automatically load .NET 4.6.1 assemblies or have them in its app domain search paths so they must be shipped with the VSIX (the exact version used).